# Why after "npm install express" there is no package.json in my directory?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using latest version of nodejs, 0.10.24

I followed this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-node-js-and-jquery/

after installing `npm install express`, I can't find the `package.json` file in the same directory.

But when I tried this on Windows a few months before, I noticed that there was a file in the same directory.

Is there anything I need to do to fix?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you `npm install module` ,the only goal is to download and save the module in ./node_module/ directory.

If you want get a package.json, you must use `npm init` and fill all the information asked.

After that, you can make `npm install module --save`, that command will download and add the module in your package.json.

Comment: great! `npm init` works quite interesting. Anyway, I am very curious that when I was trying on Windows, I never set up a `package.json` file, nor I was asked to do so.